# Base function that behaves like `cat` but returns value instead of writing to file

Tags: r, string

I am sick and tired of writing:

```
paste(paste(letters[1:3], collapse=" "), "foo")
```

In order to get:

```
[1] "a b c foo"
```

particularly because the `collapse` argument must be fully typed since it follows the `...`.  `cat` does this very easily:

```
cat(letters[1:3], "foo")
```

but does not return a value (grrr).  Is there any base (or otherwise R default preloaded package) function that behaves like `cat` does and actually returns a value?

Clearly there are several ways of building such a function, but I can't believe there isn't something already pre-existing.

One possible semi-okay solution I just thought of:

```
paste(c(letters[1:3], "foo"), collapse=" ")
```

But again annoying because of the need to fully type out `collapse`.

Comment: May be wrapping it with capture.output. ie. `capture.output(cat(letters[1:3], "foo"))`

Comment: @akrun yes, an option but hoping for a single function call.

Comment: `Reduce(paste, c(letters[1:3], 'foo'))` would also get the output you wanted, but it is also two function call.

Comment: @akrun, cute, less typing than the `paste(c(),collapse)` version too...  If no one actually knows a specialized function for this I'll take it as the answer (might give it till end of day today).  You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
Reduce(paste, c(letters[1:3], 'foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well....

```
brodiecat <- function(...) {
foo <- list(...) # sorry, I forget the syntax..
for (i in 1:length(foo)) bar[[i]] <- paste(foo[[i]], collapse=' ')
for (j in 1:length(bar) allofit <- paste(bar[[j]], collapse=' ')
}
```

Or something like that.